# Menu get hides when I toggle it in responsive mode

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive menu that in responsive mode you can toggle it with a button in jquery. The problem is when I make screen small and toggle menu (open and close it) when I return to desktop mode menu still stay hidden and this time there is no button to toggle it because it is in desktop mode and there is nothing to toggle it. only when you refresh the page menu will back.

I tried this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:873px) {
    #navbar{
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:873px) {
    #navbar{
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

and none of them works. How can I solve this problem? With css or jquery maybe?

my jquery code for toggle menu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
        $("#navbar").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, Verdana;
  background-color: #eee;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #222;
}
.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  z-index: 7;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 9;
}
a.active {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.navbar-toggle{
 display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:872px) {
 .menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
 }
 .menu li {
   float: right;
   width: 100%;
   height: 14%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 .res-menu{
  display: block;
 }
 .navbar-toggle{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
 }
 .nav-logo{
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>css3 Responsive menu effect</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
 <span class="big-font"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</button><div class="clearfix"></div>
<ul class="menu" id="navbar">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
   $("#navbar").toggle(500);
  });
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle demo for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [EnquireJS](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 873px)", {
  match: function () {
     // do something if condition is true
  },
  unmatch: function () {
     // check if navbar was closed
     if (!$("#navbar").is(":visible"))
     {
         // then open it again
         $("#navbar").toggle(500);
     }
  },
  // make this execute on start
  deferSetup: true
})
```

To test snippet run on full screen and resize the browser

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navbar-toggle").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#navbar").toggle(500);
  });

  enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 872px)", {
    match: function () {
      // if you want to do something when it is true
    },
    unmatch: function () {
      // check if navbar is not visible
      if (!$("#navbar").is(":visible")) {
        // then show it again
        $("#navbar").toggle(500);
      }
    },
    // make this execute on start
    deferSetup: true
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, Verdana;
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #222;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  z-index: 7;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 9;
}

a.active {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:872px) {
  .menu {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu li {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 14%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .res-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .nav-logo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/enquire.js/2.1.6/enquire.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>css3 Responsive menu effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
 <span class="big-font"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</button>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <ul class="menu" id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there is a problem with your code. menu getting to show and hide repetitively when I toggle it once.

Comment: @MSHDeveloper I see because it was animating, has not finished closing yet, and scroll function gets executed again, and causes the problem. I have updated the answer to fully use `enquire.js` instead.

Comment: I did whatever you did here. But the problem is still alive.

Comment: Does it also occur in your example? I don't get it what you are talking about, though based on how I understand when you click the button it opens then closes? I might be due to event propagation, I added `event.stopPropagation()` on toggle click event listener, to prevent it from happening.

Comment: look, I resize the browser to mobile screen and click on menu button to open it, then I close the menu and resize back browser to desktop mode. menu is gone and its not going to show until you refresh the page nor you are showing menu in mobile screen. (if I resize browser from mobile to desktop while menu is open, there will be not any problem.)

Comment: @MSHDeveloper man I totally misunderstood your point, You want to show it again when it goes out of your `mobile mode` and was closed. We just need to change `unmatch` callback to open it again when closed. Updated the answer\

Comment: thank you so much, just this last updated solved my problem.